# How can I draw a twisted 3D arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, rotating, 3d, tikz-arrows

Does anyone know how I can draw an 3D arrow that in itself is twisted by 90 degrees? I need such arrow to show how polarized light is twisted in a liquid crystal.

I would like to include that arrow in my tikz graphic.

EDIT: This is sort of what I want my arrow to look like. The tip and end of the arrow have to be perpendicular.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In your case, could you provide a picture to clarify what you are asking for?

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would also make a courteous addition to your post, especially since it would give us some idea of what else in your TiKZ graphic might need to be taken into account when suggesting solutions.

Comment: @cfr I have updated my post

Comment: Seems more a response to @PierPaolo's comment than mine, which your edit seems to ignore...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just playing around without really knowing what I am doing...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=orange,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1.05,.7) -- 
  (7.5,0) -- (1.3,-.7) -- (1.35,-1) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=orange,line width=1pt] (12.1,-.7) -- (11.85,.7) --
  (4.7,.4) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=orange!50,line width=1pt] (0.025,0.045) -- (.1,.3) -- (1.08,1.3) -- 
  (1,1.0) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=orange!50,line width=1pt] (1.1,1.3) -- (1,1) -- 
  (1.05,.72) -- (1.15,1) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=orange!50,line width=1pt] (1.05,.7) -- (1.15,1) -- 
   (12.1,-.7) -- (12,-1.) -- cycle;
\filldraw[fill=orange!50,line width=1pt] (1.3,-.7) -- (1.36,-.98) -- 
  (1.45,-.7) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, thats all i can say